# Using jackson to insert and remove inner nodes in a JSON?

Tags: java, jackson, jsonparser

I have a complex json, and a list of keys, which represent an arbitrary long "path" to a specific node I would like to access, remove or insert.
Is that possible?
e.g for the json

```
{
  "token": {
    "d1": 3000,
    "d2": [
      {
        "d3": "a1",
        "d4": "a2"
      }
    ],
    "d5": [
      "d6",
      "d7"
    ],

  "d8": {
    "d9": true,
    "d10": 10000
  }
}
```

and the list

```
['token','d2','d3']
```

for an insert command, the result of

```
removeFromJson(jsonString,key_path)
```

Would be

```
{
  "token": {
    "d1": 3000,
    "d2": [
      {
        "d4": "a2"
      }
    ],
    "d5": [
      "d6",
      "d7"
    ],

  "d8": {
    "d9": true,
    "d10": 10000
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, you could easily roll your own method using Jackson's [`readTree()`](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-to-jsonnode) functionality. Doing that you'd just have to descend into the tree of `JsonNode` objects according to your path (heavily simplified: `root.get("token").get("d2").remove("d3")`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd lean on `JsonNode` and, as Thomas mentioned in the comments, its `get` and `remove` methods. Something like:

```
public void remove(String json, List<String> path) {

    JsonNode root = new ObjectMapper.readTree(json);

    int lastIndex = path.size() - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < lastIndex; i++) {
        root = root.get(path.get(i));
    }

    root = root.remove(path.get(lastIndex));

    return root;
}
```

You could optimize iteration further with a sublist or a stream, and you'll probably want to handle cases in which your path doesn't actually lead to anything within the given json.

**Note:** This option works if you need this behavior on an arbitrary path within an arbitrary object - `JsonNode` is good for exactly the case in which you don't know what you'll be getting. If you *do* know what you'll be getting (it's always the same thing being removed from the same object), it's probably better form to just deserialize your JSON into an object using a mapper set to ignore fields missing in the object but present in the JSON.

Comment: The path is indeed arbitrary and I don't know what I'm getting, It worked exactly as needed.